# AngularJS $scope variable into one bind to display in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, scope

I've got problem or I'm curious if there's possibility to display in my view html from two scope variables from controller

for example in my controller is

```
$scope.lang = "en";
```

In my view it will render html like

```
{{lang}}
```

Result

```
en
```

Then I've got array like

```
   $scope.mySnippet = {
        "snippet": {
             "pl": "someLang Var",
             "en": "someLang Var EN"
        }
   }
```

And when I'll do in view

```
{{mySnippet.snippet.pl}}
```

it will result

```
someLang Var
```

**BUT** If I would combine those two $scopes into one in html for example like that

```
{{mySnippet.snippet.lang}}
```

it won't work. Expected result should be

```
someLang Var EN
```

My question is is there possibility to combine two scope variables in one bind in html view? 
I'm not sure if it is possible, and if it is, please help me :)

Thank you

Comment: Just use `[]` notation ...  `{{mySnippet.snippet[lang]}}`

Comment: Omg it was just simple as that, sorry for spending community time on such stupid thing.. Thank you very much!!